# groovy: parsing files with different extensions and using if/else

Tags: file, groovy

I have a script:

```
def tmn_file = ~/.*\.tmn/
def tmc_file = ~/.*\.tmc/
def newTerm = new Properties().with { props ->
    new File(inputPath).eachFile(tmn_file) { file ->
        file.withReader    { reader ->
            load( reader )
            println "Read data from file $file:"
            something read from file...
            switch( props.ACTION ) {
                case 'NEW':
                    do something...
                    }
            switch( props.ACTION ) {
                case 'CHANGE':
                    do something...
                    }
```

this script looking in directory with path inputPath file with extension tmn_file, which can containt ACTION - NEW or CHANGE.

Script works great, but i want to make another thing:

if file have extension *.tmn (tmn_file) - start only ACTION with NEW case

if file have extension *.tmc (tmc_file) - start only ACTION with CHANGE case

How i can realize decision?

Comment: That's not the correct usage of a switch statement... what have you tried to add your change?

Comment: A bit of theory on the switch statement in Groovy (and in every other language): [http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

> ```
> new Properties().with { props ->
>     new File(inputPath).eachFile(FileType.FILES) { file ->
>         file.withReader { reader ->
>             load(reader)
>             println "Read data from file $file:"
>
>             if (file.name.endsWith('tmn') & props.ACTION == 'NEW' || file.name.endsWith('tmc') & props.ACTION == 'CHANGE') {
>
> // NEW mode
>                 switch( props.ACTION ) {
>                     case 'NEW':
>                         ...do someth...
>                         break
>
> // CHANGE mode    
>                     case 'CHANGE':
>                         println "***CHANGE mode is on***"
>                         ...do someth...
>                         break
>                     default:
>                         throw new RuntimeException("Unknown ACTION $props.ACTION")
>                }
>
>             }  else {
>                 if (file.name.endsWith('tmn') || file.name.endsWith('tmc')){
>                 println "$file dont match for action $props.ACTION"
>                 } else {
>                 println "$file have wrong extension "}
>             }
>     }
>     }
> }
> ```